# App crashes when </ScrollView> put at end

Tags: java, android, uiscrollview

full file follows: trying to have full scroll vertical in android device but putting scroll view at end of file produces crash

```
   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
     tools:context="com.cancunsteve.aboutcancunsteve.MainActivity"
     tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:background="@mipmap/lpussy"
    android:contentDescription='android:ContentDescription="@string/desc"'
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="230dp" />


    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="serving good people with special deals. "
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:foreground="#05ffffff"
    android:foregroundTint="#03ffffff"
    android:textColor="#000000" />



    <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:text="Cancun, Playa del Carmen, Chichen Itza."
    android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:text="Holbox, Taxco, Palenque, Acapulco, Guanajuato,  
    Monterrey, Tenacatita, Mascota"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@mipmap/campa"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText5" />

    <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:text="thewebmaster@cancunsteve.com"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText" />

    <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:text="       011 52 998 8873919"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp" />

    <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:text="be sure to visit us for discounts on your hotel bookings"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/scrollView" />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="click buttons multiple times to change state"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton" />


   </RelativeLayout>`
```

when ScrollView added after Relative layout file won't open put it in brackets proceeded with backslash /
perhaps something I put in between the first and last ScrollView?
I noticed in the examples you show, scrollview appears in the beginning.

Comment: I have found the error. I have updated my answer. if it is correct, mark tick.

Comment: Dear  Suryakant, I do not see your kind answer. However I did solve it. Perhaps the same way you suggest? My problem now is it does not scroll.

Answer (score 0):

> To make `RelativeLayout` scrollable, put it inside `LinearLayout` and
>   then put that `LinearLayout` inside `ScrollView`. This will solve the
>   problem.

Use the format shown below.

```
<ScrollView xmlns: android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <RelativeLayout

            ...
            ...
            ...

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

> **UPDATE:**

**Step 1:**

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp">       <---- LOOK HERE (remove /)
```

**Step 2:**

```
     </ScrollView>    <---- LOOK HERE (end the ScrollView before RelativeLayout)
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView must have a single child.

If you want your full layout to be scrollable then add  at the top.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_grey"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:foreground="#05ffffff"
                android:foregroundTint="#03ffffff"
                android:text="serving good people with special deals. "
                android:textColor="#000000" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
                android:text="Cancun, Playa del Carmen, Chichen Itza." />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
                android:text="Holbox, Taxco, Palenque, Acapulco, Guanajuato,
    Monterrey, Tenacatita, Mascota" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText5"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:text="thewebmaster@cancunsteve.com" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:text="       011 52 998 8873919" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/scrollView"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrollView"
                android:text="be sure to visit us for discounts on your hotel bookings" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton"
                android:text="click buttons multiple times to change state" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your activity and after I removed the 2 backgrounds:

```
android:background="@mipmap/lpussy"
android:background="@mipmap/campa"
```

the activity does open fine.  
Of course the scrollview is useless the way you use it, it must contain 1 container layout and inside that container all the views that you want to scroll.  
Remove the backgrounds as well and try again. Maybe the problem is there.

Comment: but I need the two images. I will upload again the revised file which fails to open

Comment: I told you to remove the images and try again so that if the app works fine you know where the problem is. If this is the problem then you know where to look to make it right.

Comment: thanks, but going in a different direction. solved the file not opening problem. but don't have Scrolling effect. I need the images.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView xmlns: android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

your views

        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

as scroll view can only contain a sinle child , so wrapping your views in a layout will work
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your xml,
Its better to swap the top two element tags in your xml file.

So that yor RelativeLayout will become a child of ScrollView. and You dont have to edit your remaining layout elements

The result will be..

```
< ScrollView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/scrollView"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
     tools:context="com.cancunsteve.aboutcancunsteve.MainActivity"
     tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">




    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp" >
```

And it should end like..

```
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Addition:
You can replace the Relative Layout with a LinearLayout to get Rid of scrollView Errors...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="#ff0f"
        android:contentDescription='android:ContentDescription="@string/desc"'
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="serving good people with special deals. "
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:foreground="#05ffffff"
        android:foregroundTint="#03ffffff"
        android:textColor="#000000" />



    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:text="Cancun, Playa del Carmen, Chichen Itza."
        android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:text="Holbox, Taxco, Palenque, Acapulco, Guanajuato,
    Monterrey, Tenacatita, Mascota"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#f0f0"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText5" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:text="thewebmaster@cancunsteve.com"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:text="       011 52 998 8873919"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:text="be sure to visit us for discounts on your hotel bookings"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="click buttons multiple times to change state"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: that seems to work! thanks so much. file opens. now will try to build app!

Comment: file opens fine. however when oppening app in Android Studio it does not scroll

Comment: in Android Studio the light blue box outline to indicate scroll stops where the buttons begin so there's no scrolling.

Comment: think we're getting there. now just a question for it to scroll. probably you know how!

Comment: Can you try making the height of scrollview to wrap_content

Comment: file opens but does not scroll

Comment: The major reason of all this trouble is using Relative layout as a scrollview child. In my case i would always go for vertical linear layouts..

Comment: I didnt told you before becz. i thought you are having difficulty in rebuilding this xml file...

Comment: Any way the best way so far os to make a new layout xml with scrollview and linearlayout keeping the same Element ids(not mandatory to keep same ids. but it will help to reduce errors)

Comment: Hey added an alternative using LinearLayout. Edited your image resource names as i dont have them in my project. Just set it back to your image resources and try it

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
     tools:context="com.cancunsteve.aboutcancunsteve.MainActivity"
     tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp" >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:background="@mipmap/lpussy"
    android:contentDescription='android:ContentDescription="@string/desc"'
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="230dp" />


    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="serving good people with special deals. "
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:foreground="#05ffffff"
    android:foregroundTint="#03ffffff"
    android:textColor="#000000" />



    <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:text="Cancun, Playa del Carmen, Chichen Itza."
    android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:text="Holbox, Taxco, Palenque, Acapulco, Guanajuato,  
    Monterrey, Tenacatita, Mascota"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@mipmap/campa"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText5" />

    <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:text="thewebmaster@cancunsteve.com"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText" />

    <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:text="       011 52 998 8873919"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp" />

    <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:text="be sure to visit us for discounts on your hotel bookings"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/scrollView" />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="click buttons multiple times to change state"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton" />


   </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```