# Content_mail.xml file does not open

Tags: android, scrollview

The content_mail.xml file will not open. I am attempting to produce a ScrollView for the entire android screen for all views within. Code follows this is a revision of prior code posted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.cancunsteve.aboutcancunsteve.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp" />
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:background="@mipmap/lpussy"
    android:contentDescription='android:ContentDescription="@string/desc"'
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="230dp" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="       We&apos;ve been serving good people like you since 1994 with special deals on their     travel plans. "
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:foreground="#05ffffff"
    android:foregroundTint="#03ffffff"
    android:textColor="#000000" />



<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:text="Cancun, Chichen Itza."
    android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:text="Holbox, Taxco, Palenque, Acapulco, Ixtapa, Guanajuato,  
    Cabo San Lucas, Puerto Vallarta, Monterrey, Tenacatita, Mascota"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@mipmap/campa"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText5" />

    <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:text="thewebmaster@cancunsteve.com"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText" />

    <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:text="       011 52 998 8873919"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:text="be sure to visit us discounts on your hotel bookings"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/scrollView" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="click buttons multiple times to change state"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton" />


    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

The above code incorporates changes suggested as I understood them or misunderstood them. One suggestion was to remove the images. But I require them.

Comment: Please refer my below answer and check

Comment: What is your question? You cannot assume everybody saw your previous question. Please [edit] your question: trim down the code to a [mcve]. State clearly what your question is. What happens when you run your code, and what did you expect to happen instead? If you get any error message, include them in your question. Lastly, pick a better title; pick something that describes your problem in a few words. See also the [tour].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is the third question in a row about what's wrong with one specific layout file

Comment: @Steve Paul - IMO you should continue with your [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51737803/app-crashes-when-scrollview-put-at-end). You did get some good advice there, and if you still have questions you can either ask them of the authors of the various answers or you can edit your question (e.g. add a crash log if there is any) and hope that someone else is able to help

Answer (score 0):

Remove **tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"** and replace the code with below code and also replace cloasing tag `</RelativeLayout>` with `</LinearLayout>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="230dp"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:contentDescription='android:ContentDescription="@string/desc"'
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:foreground="#05ffffff"
            android:foregroundTint="#03ffffff"
            android:text="We&apos;ve been serving good people like you since 1994 with special deals on their     travel plans. "
            android:textColor="#000000" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
            android:text="Cancun, Chichen Itza." />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
            android:text="Holbox, Taxco, Palenque, Acapulco, Ixtapa, Guanajuato,
    Cabo San Lucas, Puerto Vallarta, Monterrey, Tenacatita, Mascota" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:text="thewebmaster@cancunsteve.com" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:text="011 52 998 8873919" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
            android:text="be sure to visit us discounts on your hotel bookings" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton"
            android:text="click buttons multiple times to change state" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```